# How do I import friends into Youtube?

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to import friends from Facebook or Gmail into Youtube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way for to import a contact list directly in to YouTube but it will suggest/find friends for you to add based on your Facebook and/or Gmail contacts.

First you have to enable AutoShare:

- Sign in to YouTube
- Click `Account`
- Click `Activity Sharing`
- Connect your Facebook Account

Once AutoShare has been set up when you visit the YouTube homepage you will be prompted to find your friends.

[image]

[This blog post on YouTube explains how this feature works.](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2009/12/release-notes-find-facebook-friends.html)

Full details on the [AutoShare functionality can be found here](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157215)